# How to fetch all signatures for a given ata using UMI provider with mpl-toolbox plugin?

Tags: metaplex-js, umi

Given an ata, I need to fetch all signatures and then all transaction. With the solana spl-token lib I used the below:

```
    const proceedsAddress = getProceedsAddress(program.programId, pubkey);
    const signatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(
     proceedsAddress
    );

    const transactions = await connection.getParsedTransactions(
      signatures.map((item) => item.signature),
      'finalized',
    );
```

However, it doesn't look like the UMI rpc property has the above used methods. Is there a way to access those methods using the UMI libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Umi doesn't currently support these methods in its `RpcInterface` but, for now, you have the following options:

**Option 1**: Use the catch-all `umi.rpc.call` method by passing the name of the RPC method as the first parameter and its parameters as an array in the second argument.

```
await umi.rpc.call("getSignaturesForAddress", [proceedsAddress]);
```

**Option 2**: Access the underlying `connection` object. Since right now, there's only one implementation of the `RpcInterface` and it uses the `Connection` class under the hood, you can access it via `umi.rpc.connection`. You'll have to tell TypeScript to trust you like so:

```
const { connection } = umi.rpc as { connection: Connection };
await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(proceedsAddress);
```

Comment: In option 1, the signature call worked but `getParsedTransactions` did not. Extracting connection from the umi.rpc and calling getParseTransactions did the trick. Thank you